# jQuery.extend returns function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help in the following issue:

Why `initialState` is a function?:

```
var object = function(){

    var chart = {
        state: {
            style: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
    }

     return {
        update: function() {
          _this = chart;
          _this.initialState = jQuery.extend(true, _this.state);
        },
        console: function(){
            _this = chart;
          console.log(_this)
        }
     }
}

var chart = new object();

chart.update();
chart.console();
```

Here is fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt6s40hk/

Comment: First param to `extend` should be Object. _If only one argument is supplied to `$.extend()`, this means the target argument was omitted. In this case, the jQuery object itself is assumed to be the target. By doing this, you can add new functions to the jQuery namespace. This can be useful for plugin authors wishing to add new methods to JQuery._

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much, i have tried it in a like way, but is hasnt worked also. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If target is not supplied to $.extend(), this means the target
>   argument was omitted. In this case, the jQuery object itself is
>   assumed to be the target. By doing this, you can add new functions to
>   the jQuery namespace. This can be useful for plugin authors wishing to
>   add new methods to JQuery.

Correct way

```
_this.initialState = jQuery.extend(true,{}, _this.state);
```

Comment: thank you !It has worked.Sometimes I need to spend i little bit more time to read api documentation:(